# Spatial analysis of points with different levels of precision (decimal points)

Tags: coordinate-system, spatial-statistics

I've got a dataset of points with various level of precision - some have two decimal points, other three, other four. Like this:

```
lat       lon 
23.11     120.161
45.6667  -131.12
13.441    108.567
```

I want to do two types of analysis on these points: (1) calculate distances between points, and (2) calculate centroids of groups of points. But I am not sure if I can do this since they have different levels of precision.

Do I need to round these points to the nearest common decimal (in this case two decimal points) in order to do these analyses on them? Or does it make sense to calculate distances and centroids of points as they are?

Comment: You can use what you've got, with the understanding that your precision is in the "somewhere in a neighborhood" range https://xkcd.com/2170/ It depends on what kind of analysis you want to do, but you may need to collect new data.